# Array not iterable when returned by an async function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using vuex on a project. on the store I made a function that returns, form an API, the info of all the users from an array of ids. something like this:

```
async function getUsersdata(userIds){
  let userData = new Array()
  userIds.forEach(async (id) => {
    const url = baseUrl + id + '/'
    const data = await getUserDetails(url)
    userData.push(data)
  })
  return userData 
}
```

later I use this function and when I try to do a foreach on the array that the function returns the forech doesn't work. But if console log the entire array, the array displays correctly

```
let Users = await getUsersdata(idArray)
console.log(await Users)
Users.forEach(User => console.log(User.name))
```

also when I try to console log the length of the array it returns undefined or 0, and when I use functions such as .sort() or .map() it doesn't execute either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async await doesn't work inside `forEach`, intead you should use `for` iterator.

```
async function getUsersdata(userIds){
  let userData = new Array()
  for(var i=0; i<userIds.length; i++) {
    const id = userIds[i]
    const url = baseUrl + id + '/'
    const data = await getUserDetails(url)
    userData.push(data)
  }
  return userData 
}
```

Comment: Showing `for of` here would seem superior and keep code closer to the original. Also something about why.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, perhaps someone can explain the reason behind, but you can do this:

```
await getUsersdata(idArray)
   .then(Users => {
       console.log(Users);
       Users.forEach(User => console.log(User.name)); // It works!
   });
```

Or,

```
let Users;
await getUsersdata(idArray)
   .then(data => {
       Users = data;
   });
Users.forEach(User => console.log(User.name)); // It works!
```